# Microsoft Blend: How do I scroll through the site?

Tags: silverlight, scroll, blend

I want to make a regular website with scrolling, with all the content fitting on the first screen.

I created a Silverlight Application + Website. I increased the canvas size of the UserControl and filled the entire page with my usual information.

I did Run Project. The browser starts up and shows only the first screen. The rest is truncated and scrolling does not appear.

How do I add normal scrolling to the site so that I can see the rest of the Silverlight page?

Comment: HTML code of my page: http://pastebin.com/8nUKWErC

Answer (score 1):

Your current web page HTML basically says "please resize my Silverlight Object to fit 100% of the browser".

```
<object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," 
    type="application/x-silverlight-2"
    width="100%" height="100%">
```

That means the main Silverlight Object is the same size as the Browser.

You either need to add the scrollbars in the Silverlight app or resize the Silverlight app to be bigger than the browser.

There are a couple of ways.

### 1. Use a ScrollViewer at the root of you main view

First you can just put a scrollviewer as the topmost container in your main Silverlight main page. This is simplest if it works for your specific case.

You place a Grid within the scrollviewer so that you are starting with the same basic layout you would have without a ScrollViewer.

### 2. Resize the Silverlight object dynamically

The other way (very old-school) is to change the size of the hosting Silverlight object on your page dynamically when the content of the page changes. Then you will get Web-scrollbars.

You do this by executing a Javascript call from within your main XAML window.

### In the main view constructor catch the size change:

```
LayoutRoot.SizeChanged += new SizeChangedEventHandler(LayoutRoot_SizeChanged);
```

### In the main view add the event handler:

```
    void LayoutRoot_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ResizeSilverlightObject(e.NewSize.Height);
    }

    private void ResizeSilverlightObject(double height)
    {
        // Now resize the actual Silverlight container to match the layout size
        HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("ResizeObject", new object[] { height });
    }
```

### The Javascript in the hosting ASPX/HTML page looks like

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function ResizeObject(height) {
        var host = document.getElementById("SilverlightApp");
        host.style.height = height + "px";
    }    
</script>
```

The above JavaScript assumes you have named your Silverlight object using id="SilverlightApp". e.g.

```
<object id="SilverlightApp"
    data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," 
    type="application/x-silverlight-2"
    width="100%" height="100%">
```

Whenever the Silverlight page expands to fit its content it will resize the web Silverlight object to the same size as the page. The web-browser scroll-bars will then work normally.

Comment: When I do the first method (1. Use a ScrollViewer at the root of you main view), adding ScrollViewer or changing LayoutRoot with Grid on ScrollViewer, I can insert only one object at ScrollViewer. It's stands at the center of the layer. If I insert another object (such as the Button to add the TextBox), the first object disappears. I tested it on an empty project.

Comment: A ScrollViewer can only have one child, but if that is a grid (or a canvas) you can have anything you want it in. I will explain more clearly.

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution! When creating the project to choose Silverlight **SketchFlow** Application. **Not exactly** what you want, but at least it works **fine**.

Comment: That is an accidental side-effect of a SKetchflow project and certainly not something you want to tell other people to do (to solve the problem you outlined).

Comment: I agree with @HiTech Magic. Don't consider this a solution to your problem. Sketchflow is a prototyping tool.